# Track position to animate transition between Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-animation

I am applying a transition to fragment, and I found a solution that suits my need. in here [Fragment transition animations with BottomNavigationView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54355204/fragment-transition-animations-with-bottomnavigationview/54359057#54359057)

here is the code

```
private boolean loadFragment(Fragment fragment, int newPosition) {
if(fragment != null) {
    if(newPosition == 0) {
        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.contentLayout, fragment).commit();

   }
    if(startingPosition > newPosition) {
        getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
                .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_right )
            .replace(R.id.contentLayout, fragment).commit();

    }
    if(startingPosition < newPosition) {
        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left)
                .replace(R.id.contentLayout, fragment).commit();

    }
    startingPosition = newPosition;
    return true;
}

return false; }
```

the `startingPosition` can't be resolved, and I don't know how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

you have to define `startingPosition` above your function in your class like that :

```
int startingPosition = 0;
private boolean loadFragment(Fragment fragment, int newPosition) {
if(fragment != null) {
    if(newPosition == 0) {
        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.contentLayout, fragment).commit();

   }
    if(startingPosition > newPosition) {
        getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
                .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_right )
            .replace(R.id.contentLayout, fragment).commit();

    }
    if(startingPosition < newPosition) {
        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left)
                .replace(R.id.contentLayout, fragment).commit();

    }
    startingPosition = newPosition;
    return true;
}

return false; }
```